# Bridge in Debian Linux (Wheezy) cannot access WAN hosts by name

Tags: linux, bridge, debian-wheezy

I'm having the same problem as this poster:
[bridging two network interfaces in ubuntu linux 12.10 AND being able to access it from that machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/469422/bridging-two-network-interfaces-in-ubuntu-linux-12-10-and-being-able-to-access-i)
and would be grateful for any help on how to debug it.

I'm assuming that a bridge with a single port (eth2) should work the same as eth2 did without the bridge.

System: Debian Linux (Wheezy) 64-bit, single NIC, Belkin wireless router.

My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth2
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

After bringing up br0, when I try to ping WAN hosts, the ping command just hangs until I kill it.  I can do

```
# dig google.com
```

and that works fine, and I can successfully ping the numeric IP address returned by dig.

---

@MariusMatutiae:
Have tried adding the dns-nameservers line, but it made no difference.
This may be because ifup causes /etc/resolv.conf to be overwritten with 192.168.2.1, the DNS server address of the router.
However, this may be a red herring.  If I do

```
# dig google.com
```

it still gives a correct answer.  In fact, if I edit /etc/resolv.conf and remove all nameserver entries, then

```
# dig @192.168.2.1 google.com
```

still gives a correct answer.  So, if dig can do it, why can't ping?

Comment: I am confused by your configuration.  You have br0 set to DHCP, but you have also specified a gateway/netmask/broadcast, but no address?  What exactly are you trying to do here?  Is it supposed to be DHCP or static.  If DHCP remove the extraneous settings, of static, then set it as static, and give it a valid address.

Comment: Sorry, too much cutting/pasting during experimenting made a mess of my /etc/interfaces ! Have removed the static stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to include DNS nameservers, which you must provide since your brdge is not a DHCP client of your router.

In /etc/network/interfaces, always in the br0 stanza, include the line

```
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

or whichever you like